# Does JavaScriptSerializer ignore CurrentThread.CurrentCulture in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to understand if JavaScriptSerializer that is used internally for serializing data to JSON in ASP.net MVC 4 ignores the current thread's CultureInfo.

**My current observations are below.**

I set the culture info properties in Application_AuthenticateRequest method in global.asax

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
```

If I return a regular View, the UI and data are serialized properly according to the culture
For example, labels are converted to Spanish and  credit and debit values show up on the screen as expected with comma in place of decimal point.

**Vorname    Nachname    DOB     Erstellungsdatum    Datum aktualisiert  Credit  Debit**
sfds     sfdsfds     11-11-2013  29/10/2013 18:20:29     30/10/2013 22:29:20     11,00   11,00

But when I return a JSON result, numbers are not formatted according to culture. As shown below credit and debit values have decimal point instead of comma. I did not have any luck with JSON.net library as well.

{ "CreateDate" : "/Date(1383085229737)/",
  "Credit" : 11.0,
  "DOB" : "/Date(1384146000000)/",
  "Debit" : 11.0,
  "FirstName" : "sfds",
  "Id" : 1,
  "LastName" : "sfdsfds",
  "UpdateDate" : "/Date(1383186560390)/"
}

**My question is, is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?**

Comment: Are you not surprised that the dates don't look like dates either? JSON is encoding string representations of the values, not string representations of string representations of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is this the expected behavior

Yes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you point me to some resources on how to format this data on the client as per the culture.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString